# Chain Rule partial derivatives and the wave equation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, wave-equation, chain-rule

Let $c>0$ be a constant and suppose that $f$ is a $C^2$ function of $x+ct$ plus a $C^2$ function of $x−ct$. That is, $f(x,t)=g(x+ct)+h(x−ct)$ where $g:R→R$ and $h:R→R$ are $C^2$ functions.

Show that such an $f$ is always a solution of the wave equation $c^2f_{xx}=f_{tt}$
and show that any $C^2$ solution of the wave equation $c^2f_{xx}=f_{tt}$ must be of the form $f(x,y)=g(x+ct)+h(x−ct)$.

If anyone can prove this would much appreciated it!

Answer (score 1):

Compute $f_{xx}$ and $f_{tt}$ using the chain rule:

$$f_{xx} = g_{xx} + h_{xx},\\
= g''(x+ct) + h''(x-ct)
$$

and

$$f_{tt} = g_{tt} + h_{tt},\\
=c^2g''(x+ct) + c^2h''(x-ct)
$$

Now substitute into the wave equation:

$$c^2 f_{xx} = f_{tt},
\implies c^2 \left(g''(x+ct) + h''(x-ct)\right) = c^2g''(x+ct) + c^2h''(x-ct)$$

and we can see both sides are equal.

For the second part of the question, define new variables,
$$\xi = x+ct, \eta = x-ct$$
and find expressions for the operators $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}, \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ in terms of these variables (use the chain rule). If you get stuck on this part see section 2 of this [link](https://www.iist.ac.in/sites/default/files/people/IN08026/dAlembert.pdf)